# How do I define function for part of typenames

Tags: c++, type-traits

I have a code like this

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
};

template <typename T>
struct A {
    static int a();
};

template <>
int A<int>::a() {
    return 42;
}

template <>
int A<X>::a() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << A<int>().a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << A<X>().a() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to return 42 for all types that are arithmetic i.e such that `std::is_arithmetic<T>::type` is `std::true_type`

I've tried

```
template <typename T, typename U = std::true_type>
struct A {
    static int a();
};

template <typename T>
int A<T, typename std::is_arithmetic<T>::type>::a() {
    return 42;
}
```

But I got following error:

```
a.cpp:12:51: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct A<T, typename std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::type>’
 int A<T, typename std::is_arithmetic<T>::type>::a() {
                                                   ^
a.cpp:7:8: error: declaration of ‘struct A<T, typename std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::type>’
 struct A {
        ^
```

and also tried

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    static int a();
};

template <typename T, typename E = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
int A<T>::a() {
    return 42;
}
```

Error:

```
a.cpp:12:13: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing ‘static int A<T>::a()’
 int A<T>::a() {
             ^
a.cpp:12:13: error: got 2 template parameters for ‘static int A<T>::a()’
a.cpp:12:13: error:   but 1 required
```

What is correct way to achieve this? Does it exist at all?

I know I can do that, specializing all struct at once, but I don't want this because there are actually several functions more, that should be common

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not going to work.  Instead, try defining a separate type that will contain either 42 or 0, based on is_arithmetic.  You can use boost::mpl::if_ for the purpose:

```
template< typename T > struct Res
{
    typedef typename if_<
          std::is_arithmetic<T>
        , static_value<42>
        , static_value<0>
        >::type value;
};
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to be able to add other values for other classes

Comment: You can chain if_s as much as you like, or use other MPL constructs.  And since the "values" are types, these types can implement any functionality you want.  Or you can simply provide specialized versions yourself, but then you will have to do so for every integer class separately.